# Disable Windows Hello Power Saving Mode

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607, kinect, windows-hello

On my PC running Windows 10 x64 version 1607 with a Kinect v2 hooked up to it, I have the system configured to use Windows Hello facial recognition to unlock the computer.

After a while of sitting locked, the lock screen goes from "Looking for you" to "Windows Hello is in Power Saving Mode" and requires a keypress to re-activate Windows Hello.

As the system is a desktop, I have no need for power saving functionality, especially when it harms the user experience. How can I disable this power-saving mode so that the computer will unlock without a keypress, even after having been locked for an extended period of time?

I think this power saving mode was added with the 1607 update, as I do not recall it happening when I first set up the system.

Note that I am on the "High Performance" power profile in the control panel power settings dialog.

Comment: Good question. It's been asked on Reddit a few months ago with no responses: https://www.reddit.com/r/windows/comments/5kf7w7/disable_windows_hello_power_saving_mode/ I'd look at the power settings for the Kinect in the Device Manager.

Comment: @music2myear Unchecking this box ( http://i.imgur.com/QB0WpPi.png ) had no effect.

Comment: Ok. Having never seen or troubleshot this issue myself, and only finding that one other reference so far, that was my one thing I'd try if I saw the problem, and apparently it's not the right thing. I'll google a bit more, but you may want to send some Feedback using the Win10 Feedback app that's probably in your start menu. Or try a Microsoft support forum. We may get luck and someone here has seen and fixed the issue before, but considering how little I find about this problem online, I'm not betting too heavily on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticket with Microsoft about this, and after three months of troubleshooting they concluded that the only way to disable Windows Hello power saving mode is to uninstall all the patches on Version 1607 of Windows 10, and that going forward (including in the Creator's update) disabling Windows Hello power saving mode is unsupported and impossible.